# Are these 3 vectors linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $u_1=(i,2,0) $, $u_2=(1,1+i,0)  $, $u_3=(-1,1,1)  $, is $\{u_1,u_2,u_3\}$ a basis of $\mathbb{C}^3$ over $\mathbb{C}?$ I know that I first have to show if the vectors are linearly independent but I'm not sure how to do this part!

Comment: You have to say over what field

Comment: Well, which ways do you know to show linear independence? Determinants? Systems of linear equations?

Comment: their viewed as a vector space over C. why does it matter?

Comment: I normally do a system of linear equations

Comment: Shortcut - any linear combination of u1 and u2 will have 0 in the 3rd co-ordinate, whereas the 3rd co-ordinate of u3 is not 0. So you just have to show that u1 and u2 are linearly independent i.e. is u2 a multiple of u1 or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $u_1$, $u_2$, and $u_3$ were linearly dependent then there would exist $c_1,c_2,c_4\in\mathbb{C}$ not all $0$ where $$c_1 u_1+c_2u_2+c_3u_3=0.$$  So you just have to show that for any $c_1,c_2,c_3$ satisfying the above equation all coefficients are identically $0$. Suppose you have three such coefficients, just considering the third component of each side of this equation we have that $c_3 = 0$ (since $u_1$ and $u_2$ all have $0$ in their third component).

Hence we have that $c_1 u_1 = -c_2 u_2$. So you only have to check if $u_2$ is a multiple of $u_1$. 
$$ic_1 = -c_2 \quad\qquad(1)$$ $$2c_1=-c_2+c_2i\,\,\,(2)$$
Hence $c_1=ic_2$ (from $(1)$). So from $(2)$ $$2ic_2=-c_2+c_2i\qquad (3)$$ Therefore $c_2=0$ (since supposing $c_2\neq 0$, we could divide $c_2$ from both sides of $(3)$ to obtain $2i=-1+i\implies i=-1$, which is nonsense).

Hence $c_1=c_2=c_3=0$ and so $u_1,u_2$ and $u_3$ are linearly independent.

Edit: This all follows from [gandalf61](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/424513/gandalf61)'s "shortcut" comment.